# Как преобразовать файл картинку в jpg ссылку?

Tags: java, android, jpeg

```
"avatar": {
    "id": "585cda2047c3b5000d24e8a9",
    "path": "/uploads/avatars/584fcd8d2880960011927a88/0062521347",
    "color": "#595959"
}
```

Мне нужно `path` преобразовать в `jpg` ссылку, но не знаю как это можно сделать.

Как лучше это сделать с `ImageView`?

Comment: что такое эта jpg ссылка?

Comment: Так не работает? 
String jpgFileName = "/uploads/avatars/584fcd8d2880960011927a88/0062521347" + ".jpg";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, для отображения картинки не обязательно иметь расширение

```
File imgFile = new  File("/uploads/avatars/584fcd8d2880960011927a88/0062521347");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

и не забудьте взять пермишен (а для Андроид выше 6 ещё и динамический пермишен)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```